# What's worth testing in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I'm doing a contract job in Ruby on Rails and it is turning into a disaster for productivity largely because of writing tests. This is my first time using TDD in practice and it hasn't gone well because I am spending so much time writing tests that I've hardly gotten any results to show. I'm thinking that perhaps I'm trying to test too much by writing tests for every feature in each model and controller.

If I can't aim for 100% test coverage, what are some criteria that I could use to determine "is this feature worth testing"?  For example, would integration tests trump unit tests?

Answer (score 2):

If you're just getting started with testing in the ruby or Rails world, I'd make the following suggestions:

- Start with rspec. Automated acceptance/integration testing with a tool like Cucumber can be a large timesink for a single developer who has never used it before. Success with those tools is often contingent upon A) quality UI specs that are very very specific, B) UI conventions which are easily testable with headless browser emulators and C) Familiarity with the tools ahead of go time.
- Test individual methods. Test that they return the values you expect. Test that when you feed them bad data, they respond in an appropriate manner. Test any edge cases as you become aware of them.
- Be very careful that you are stubbing and mocking correctly in your tests. It's easy to write a test for 30 minutes only to discover that you're not really testing the thing you need to be testing.
- Don't go overboard with micro-managing your TDD - some folks will tell you to test every tiny step in writing a method: first test that the model has a method called 'foo', then test whether it returns non-nil, then test that it returns a string, then test that the string contains a certain substring. While this approach can be helpful when you're implementing something complex, it can be a time sink as well. Just skip the first two steps. That being said, it's easy to go too far in the other direction, specifying a method's behavior with a complex test before you begin implementing it, then beginning the implementation only to find you've botched the test.
- Don't write tests that just say 'this is how i wrote the feature, don't change it'. Tests should reflect the essential business logic of a method. If you are writing tests specifically so that they will fail if another developer changes some non-critical part of your implementation, you are wasting time and adding superfluous lines of code.

These are just a few observations I've made from having been in similar situations. Best of luck, testing can be a lot of fun! No, really. I mean it.

Answer (score 2):

100% test coverage is a fantasy and a waste of time.  Your tests should serve a purpose, typically to give you confidence that the code you wrote works.  Not absolute confidence, but some amount of confidence.  TDD should be a tool, not a restriction.

If it's not making your work come out better, why are you doing it?  More importantly, if you fail to produce useful code and lose the contract, *those tests weren't too useful after all were they*?  It's a balance, and it sounds like you're on the wrong side.

If you're new to Rails, you can get a small dose of its opinionated creator's view on testing [in this 37signals blog article on the topic](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3159-testing-like-the-tsa).  Small rules of thumb, but maybe something to push you in a new direction on the subject.

There are also good references on improving your use of RSpec like [betterspecs.org](http://betterspecs.org), [The RSpec Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356379) and [Everyday Rails Testing with RSpec](https://leanpub.com/everydayrailsrspec).  Using it poorly can result in a lot of headache maintaining the specs.

Comment: DHH's blog post is one of the things that prompted me to ask this question. So many developers tell me that TDD should be intertwined into your coding practice, but to me that would lead to 100% test coverage and slow your development. Most of the developers I know - although they advocate testing - many don't do it themselves if at all.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to try and get your testing and your writing of code as tightly coupled as possible, combined with an Agile approach to the project.

This way you will constantly have new stuff to show the client as testing will just be baked in.  The biggest mistake I see with teams that are new to testing is to continue to see the testing as a separate activity. Most of all I continue to see developers say that a feature is done... but will need some refactoring and some better tests at "some points".  "Some point" rarely comes.  One thing is inescapable though - at least for several months it *will* be much slower in the short term but much better quality and you'll avoid building the "[big ball of mud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud)" I've seem in so many larger institutions.

Comment: How could you combine TDD and Agile?... to me it would seem that because Agile is about dealing with changing requirements, one of the problems with that philosophy is that a changed requirement leads to double work of changing the code AND the tests.

Comment: Many organizations that I've worked with find this to be helpful.  Agile helps drive software that meets the users requirements and tdd helps drives the technical detailed component of that

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

**Don't**

- Test the database
- Test ActiveRecord or whatever ORM you're using

**Do**

For models:

- Test validations
- Test custom logic

For controllers:

- Test non-trivial routes
- Test redirects
- Test authentication
- Test instance variable assignment

For views:

I haven't gotten around to testing views, but I've run into situations where I wish I did.  For example testing fields in forms.

More at [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html)

Comment: When you say 'test validations', do you mean _custom_ validations? In general, I try to always remind myself not to test Rails' code. This includes out-of-the-box validations. Now custom validations are another story entirely.

Comment: @Charles I agree with not testing rails code.  However, I do include validations like `validates_presence_of` etc. in my specs because they describe what model attributes are required, should be unique, etc.